# Abstract data type/unindexed columns in IxSet

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, abstract-data-type

`Data.IxSet` from `ixset` library provides multicolumn tables with indices for each column and computed indices for non-existent columns.

How can I put an abstract value there in an unindexed column?

Here is an example. I have `Lib` module that exports `Abstract` type without any constructors but with some functions to manipulate the opaque values.

```
module Lib (Abstract, makeAbstract) where
data Abstract = Abstract (Int -> Int)
makeAbstract x = Abstract (\x -> 42 * x + y)
```

I can have normal map such as `Map String Abstract` as value type is unconstrained there. But I cannot have `IxSet Table` which is sort of `(Map String Abstract, Map Int Abstract)`:

```
module User where
import Lib

data Table = Table { tKey1 :: String, tKey2 :: Int, tValue :: Abstract }
```

Because I'm required to provide an `instance Data Table`. Ideally I'd like to have `newtype Opaque a = Opaque a` which has all necessary instances for any `a` without imposing constraints on it, and use something like:

```
data Table = Table { tKey1 :: String, tKey2 :: Int, tValue :: Opaque Abstract }
  deriving (Data, Typable, ...)
```

Comment: Why are you required to provide `instance Data Table`? I don't remember this requirement for `ixset`. I think it's only needed for `ixGen`.

Comment: Yes it's only needed for `ixGen`

Comment: But you wouldn't use `ixGen` on an abstract type, so I still don't understand the question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `instance Indexable Table`? `Table` is not abstract but it has an abstract field